# Is it possible to monitor all write access to the filesystem of all process under linux

Tags: linux, logging, filesystems, system-calls

Is it possible to monitor all write access to the filesystem of all process under linux?

I've some different mounted filesystems. A lot of them are tempfs.

I'm interested in all writes to the root filesystem except the tempfs,devtmpfs etc.

I'm looking for something that will output: `<PID xy> write n Bytes to /targe/filepath`.
What monitoring tool can list all this write syscalls? Can they be filtered by mount points?

Comment: Cross-posted:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450840/is-it-possible-to-monitor-all-write-access-to-the-filesystem-of-all-process

Comment: The answer is still the same:  [auditing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing)

Answer (score 2):

### fatrace (File Activity Trace)

[fatrace](https://github.com/martinpitt/fatrace) reports file access events (Open, Read, Write, Close) from **all** running processes. Its main purpose is to find processes which keep waking up the disk unnecessarily and thus prevent some power saving.

When running it outputs one line per event in this format:

```
<timestamp> <processName(id)>: <accessType> </path/to/file>
```

For example:

```
23:10:21.375341 Plex Media Serv(2290): W /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-UID/Plex/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Logs/Plex Media Server.log
```

#### From which you easily get the all necessary infos

- Timestamp from the --timestamp option
- Process name (who is accessing)
- File operation (O-pen R-read W-rite C-lose)
- Filepath (where is it writing to).
- You can limit the search scope with `--current-mount` to only record events on partition/mount of current directory.

  - So simply `cd` into the volume which corresponds to your spinning HDD first, and there run ftrace with the `--current-mount` option.
- Without this option, all  (real)  partitions/mount points are being watched.

### Very practical

With it I found out easily that the reason why my NAS disk was spinning 24/7 also when nobody accessed the NAS and also no maintenance tasks where about to run was unnecessary logging of the Plex Media Server.

Answer (score 1):

[iotop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) (kernel version 2.6.20 or higher) or [dstat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat) could help you. E.g. `iotop -o -b -d 10` like discussed in this [similar thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44103/how-to-find-which-process-is-regularly-writing-to-disk).

Answer (score 1):

/proc/diskstats has data for all the block devices.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt

```
  The /proc/diskstats file displays the I/O statistics of block devices. Each line contains the following 14 fields:
             1 - major number
             2 - minor mumber
             3 - device name
             4 - reads completed successfully
             5 - reads merged
             6 - sectors read
             7 - time spent reading (ms)
             8 - writes completed
             9 - writes merged
            10 - sectors written
            11 - time spent writing (ms)
            12 - I/Os currently in progress
            13 - time spent doing I/Os (ms)
            14 - weighted time spent doing I/Os (ms)
            For more details refer to Documentation/iostats.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/) script to monitor filesystem operations. Maybe you can visit the [Brendan D. Gregg's blog](http://www.brendangregg.com/index.html), where there are many monitor tools.